# Powershell remove-snapshot cmdlet

Tags: powershell, vmware

I'm working on a small script that will get all the snapshots in a VM and remove all snapshots in the VM except for the 6 newest snapshots, based off the description.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
get-snapshot -vm "test" | sort -property description | remove-snapshot ?
```

I am using get-date to make the description for each VM be the date on which it was created, and want to remove all but the 6 newest snapshots. What am I missing with my script to accomplish this task?

I was thinking of using the -getchildren however I'm unable to figure out how to get it to where it would delete snapshots 7 and on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A snapshot has a property called Created so you can sort on this property and skip the first 6. Test this in a test environment and remove the WhatIf switch to delete the snapshots.

```
Get-Snapshot -VM test | 
Sort-Object Created | 
Select-Object -Skip 6 | 
Remove-Snapshot -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
```

Comment: Hello Shay Levy,

Whenever I try this, it seems to be working however I do have one question. I was testing this today and created 8 snapshots and named them test1, test2, ... , test8.

When I tested this I noticed that the sort-object creation would select test1, test2, etc. however the two that it would skip and consider the last to be created were test3 and test4 in my testing environment.

Strangely enough, when I tested this by sorting based off the description and making the description a get-date variable, it would react the same.

Comment: Would you happen to know why when it sorts, test1 and test2 aren't the ones being picked as the oldest snapshots?

Comment: When you run: 'Get-Snapshot -VM test | Sort-Object Creation | Select-Object -Skip 6' which snapshots are shown in the output, the most new or old ones?

Comment: Whenever I run just 'Get-Snapshot -VM test | sort-object Creation' the snapshots were outputted as such: 'test6, test5, test8, test7, test2, test1, test4, test3' in that order. (figured would be better to show all rather than adding -skip 6 for now)

Comment: Quick note: these snapshots were created relatively near the same time. Would that affect how the sorting works when it is getting the creation? I tested also using 'get-snapshot -vm TEST | sort -property description' where description for each snapshot is a $date variable ($date = get-date). The output when I did this was identical to your method.

Comment: Even though the snapshot names are "out of order", do they come out sorted by creation as expected?

Comment: I recreated all my snapshots to test again with more time in between each snapshot and noticed something peculiar: the creation sort method gave the same output again, however this time the sort -property description -descending (with description being date of creation) was correctly outputting the desired results. Strange that the creation sort method is giving such a weird output, would you happen to know why it does this?

Comment: @Julian Just to verify, regardless of snapshot names, when you run  'Get-Snapshot -VM test | sort-object Creation', do they come out sorted by creation date?

Comment: looks like created is what we're looking for, not creation.  however, when we remove more than one snapshot, the command prompt wants to wait for confirmation before removing.  there's no -force to remove-snapshot that i can see.  ideas?

Comment: I can't test it now but will look into it tomorrow. To suppress confirmations use -Confirm:$false (I added that to my answer).

Comment: My bad @Julian, the property is called 'Created', not 'Creation'! I updated it in my answer.